# Error: incompatible element type schema.sobjectfield for collection of id

Tags: trigger

Requirement: whenever a case is inserted or updated, if owner of the case is a user (not a queue and except one user), change the status of case to closed.

My code:

```
trigger CaseTriggerTest1 on Case (after insert, after update) {

    list<id> ownerIds = new list<id>();
    if(case.ownerid != null && case.ownerid != '005o0000000LVQG'){
        if(case.ownerId.getSObjectType() == User.SObjectType) {
            ownerIds.add(case.OwnerId);
        }
    }

    for(case c : trigger.new){
        if (c.OwnerId =: ownerIds){
            c.status = 'closed';
        }
    }
}
```

**Errors**:

1) at the line `ownerIds.add(case.OwnerId);`, I am getting error: "incompatible element type schema.sobjectfield for collection of id"

2) I am not sure how to check if owner id is in a list at `c.OwnerId =: ownerIds`, Need some suggestion here

Also, kindly suggest if there is a better way to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Case.OwnerId`, you are retrieving the corresponding `Schema.SObjectField`, e.g.:

```
Schema.SObjectField caseOwner = Case.OwnerId;
```

If you would like to get the `OwnerId` for a specific `Case` record, you need to reference just that record. Here you would probably use a loop:

```
for (Case newCase : trigger.new)
{
    if (newCase.OwnerId != null) // and whatever else
}
```

Note that the above is just like your second loop, except it uses a more informatively named loop variable.

**You should never hard code Ids.** In this instance, you want a `Set<Id>` so that you can use the `contains` method. The simplest way to find those users might be to query by `Username` or add them to a `Group` or `Permission Set`, depending on your requirements.

```
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
for (User owner : [
    SELECT Id FROM User
    WHERE Username IN ('user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com')
])
{
    ownerIds.add(owner.Id);
}

//later...
if (ownerIds.contains(newCase.ownerId))
{
    // do stuff
}
```